# predicting the color of the next card drawn

Tags: r, probability

[edited based on comment and answer offered]

Note: This question is different from [Guess the color of the next card](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175288/guess-the-color-of-the-next-card) as that question asks for the payoff of a slightly different game.

This question asks if there is a strategy to win. One comment gave as a strategy, "Wait until the last card is to be drawn, then predict it with 100% accuracy". A similar strategy would be to wait until more cards of one color have been overturned, then predict that the next card will be of the other color.

But is there an optimal or best number for the value of "ahead", the difference in the count of one color vs the other that have so far been dealt?

This problem feels similar in some ways to the Secretary Problem, but I can't provide reasoning for that assertion.

--

A card is drawn one by one from a shuffled deck. At each draw, you can either pass (draw the card with no prediction), or predict the color of the next card.

At the start, you can predict red with 50% chance of success. What is a strategy to make a better prediction?

My strategy is to see some draws, wait till one color is "ahead" by a certain amount, then predict the other color on the next draw.

That entails knowing how much "ahead" I should allow one color to get before the prediction.

I ran a simulation of this to discover what a reasonable amount of "ahead" to wait for would be, assigning -1 to red and +1 to black and taking a sum.

My questions are:

- How do I determine the right value of "ahead" to make the prediction?
- In R, how do I find the location and value of that value in the cum vector

```html
set seed(100)
sim <- replicate(1000000, {cum <- cumsum(sample(c(-1,1), size=52, replace=TRUE));
max(abs(cum))})
summary(sim)

> summary(sim)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.000   6.000   8.000   8.567  11.000  34.000
```

Comment: Check this: sim <- replicate(1000000, {max(abs(cumsum(sample(c(-1,1), size=52, replace=TRUE))))}) table(sim)

Comment: On the one hand a bigger value of "ahead" is better than a small value; on the other hand I may hold out for a larger "ahead" which never happens, and thus lose the advantage of one color being "ahead".

Comment: got it, it's one single guess, not iterating. You can guess the last card 100%

Comment: Could you explain the distinction between finding a "strategy to win" and evaluating the payoff of the game?  Those seem like perfectly equivalent things.  Evaluating the payoff of course means when the game is played to win and not in some inferior way.

Comment: Hm. I had it in my mind that there might be a way to 'game' this, since there are times when the ability to predict the next card IS greater than 50%, such as predicting the last card to be drawn. Also, the task described in the other post does not predict the next card, it just wins if red is drawn. If you wait for the last card, it could be black, so the 'wait for last card' strategy that words here does not work in that case.  BUT.. maybe there is no way to 'game' this, and that's what the proof means in the other post. I could not fully follow that proof.

Comment: There may be variations of this game that differ from the one described in the duplicate.  The advantage the dup currently holds over your question is that it is answerable: yours cannot be answered until you can quantify how "optimal" or "best" will be determined.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, thank you. I want weight the guess so "earlier" is better. The original question came from a youtube video of a first class in machine learning; the teacher said it was an interview question he received. Hopefully video 2 will answer it :-).